# Is it possible to preallocate memory for List<double>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, memory

Is it possible to preallocate memory for `List<double>` in .NET 4.5 using C#?
I'm adding millions of data to my list. I know it would be much more efficient if I could preallocate some memory before writing to it.

Is it possible?

Update:
I'm capturing data from external sensor.
I don't know how much data I will get. That is why I'm using list.

Comment: Set the Capacity property for this, which can alos be done by passing in the required capacity to the constructor.

Comment: How is the documentation unclear?

Comment: Also, the dynamic allocation is at most a *2 penalty on the allocation itself, which is still O(N). Usually your actual processing dwarfs this considerably.

Comment: Also, this seems like a really, really bad idea. Lists were not designed to hold megabytes of data.

Comment: @EricLippert If a List is backed by an array, why not (in comparison to just an array)? A few [tens of] megabytes of data doesn't *necessarily* seem bad ..

Comment: @pst: If that's what you want then what's the advantage of a list? Use an array if you want the performance characteristics of an array.

Comment: @EricLippert I still don't understand why a List is a "really, really bad idea". The question is about allocations - let's say the initial capacity is specified. Why then would it be preferable to use an array directly? I'm not saying that it's *good*, but I don't see how it is *necessarily* bad .. I know you have lots of insight into this stuff, and the previous comments seem lacking in reason.

Comment: @pst: because when you have a list, you want to do listy things to it. Add items to the end. Remove them from the middle. And so on. These operations are not efficient if the list is enormous. Handing someone a list like that is essentially handing them a bomb and hoping they don't trigger it. If you don't want to do listy things to your collection then don't make it a list in the first place.

Comment: @pst: What is worse though is that (1) the question shows a total lack of research, and (2) though I agree it is wise to think of performance up front, and though we know nothing about what the questioner is going to do with these data, it smacks of premature optimization to worry about saving on the reallocation but not thinking "is it even sensible to put all this into a list in the first place"?

Comment: @EricLippert Now that is a reason / explanation that makes sense to me - thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Trivially:

```
var list = new List<double>(2000000);
```

Allocates space for 2M doubles.

Comment: @user166390 That made me laugh.